# Check login on every activity

Tags: android, android-activity, authentication, titlebar

I'm developing and app where the user must login before using it. I customized my titlebar and put a logout button there, to enable users to logout whenever they want, and login with another account. The app should then display the login activity again.

That works well, but my problem is with the back button. When the user logs out, the login activity show up, but if he presses back, the app returns to the previous page, enabling the user to use that activity again, even without login.

I have my `onCreate()` of every activity set up this way:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    // Activity code  
    checkLogin();  
}
```

And the `checkLogin()`:

```
if (GlobalContext.getCurrentUser() == null) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, GlobalContext.REQUEST_LOGIN);
}
```

However that's not working like it should, my app crashes sometimes when I press back, sometimes it return to the previous activity like I said, and sometimes it does actually work.

How can I make the `checkLogin()` get called everytime the activity is (re)started?
Or there is another, better way to do what I want?

EDIT:

Based on @Gabriel's answer and the following diagram from [the SDK references](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle), I moved the `checkLogin()` to the `onResume()` method instead of the `onCreate`, solving my problem.

[image: Activity life cycle]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the call to `checkLogin()` from `onCreate()` to `onStart()`.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed. I actually moved it to onResume, worked well

Answer (score 5):

What I suggest is to add you `checkLogin()` to acitivity `onResume()` as checking it in `onCreate()` method will cause to call check for login 1 time only when activity created.

Or even batter is to move it to

```
onAttachToWindow()
```

So every time your activity will come to front. `onAttachToWindow()` will be called and will check for login.

Answer (score 4):

In the fisrt Activity where the user logged in , try to Save a variable on your SharedPreferences like this :

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("logged", true); // set it to false when the user is logged out

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
```

And then in every Activity of yours , put this code to check if the user is logged in or not , if he is not logged in , so redirect him to the LoginActivity like this :

```
@Override
    protected void onStart(Bundle state){
       super.onStart(state);
       . . .

       // Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       boolean loggedIn = settings.getBoolean("logged", true);
       if(!loggedIn){
            Toast.makeText(this,"you are not logged in !!",3000).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
       }
    }
```

Comment: This check you're doing with the SharedPreferences have the same result of the check I'm doing with the getCurrentUser(), so it's kinda pointless (and wrong, I'll explain) to store the login status. It's wrong because the app doesn't save the login after it's closed, so I'd have to check when the app quits to set this preference to false. But moving the check from onCreate to onStart solved my problem

Comment: and for more performances ,  you also should add the test of the boolean loggedIn ,on the method onResume()