# After user signs in I don't want sign in activity to show up again unless user logs out

Tags: android

OK so I have a LoginActivity. When user signs in I don't want the activity to show up again unless the user signs out. How should I do this? I am fairly new to android, so please bear with me. This is just a bare example from the ADT I plan on adding my database functionality later, but for now I am just keeping it as is for testing purposes.

```
package com.example.imet;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
* Activity which displays a login screen to the user, offering registration as
* well.
*/
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/**
 * A dummy authentication store containing known user names and passwords.
 * TODO: remove after connecting to a real authentication system.
 */
private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[] {
        "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world" };

/**
 * The default email to populate the email field with.
 */
public static final String EXTRA_EMAIL = "com.example.android.authenticatordemo.extra.EMAIL";

/**
 * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
 */
private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

// Values for email and password at the time of the login attempt.
private String mEmail;
private String mPassword;

// UI references.
private EditText mEmailView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private View mLoginFormView;
private View mLoginStatusView;
private TextView mLoginStatusMessageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the login form.
    mEmail = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL);
    mEmailView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mEmailView.setText(mEmail);

    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordView
            .setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id,
                        KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                        attemptLogin();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mLoginStatusView = findViewById(R.id.login_status);
    mLoginStatusMessageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_status_message);

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    attemptLogin();
                }
            });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
 * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
 * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
 */
public void attemptLogin() {
    if (mAuthTask != null) {
        return;
    }

    // Reset errors.
    mEmailView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    mEmail = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    mPassword = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    // Check for a valid password.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mPassword)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (mPassword.length() < 4) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for a valid email address.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEmail)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (!mEmail.contains("@")) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
        // perform the user login attempt.
        mLoginStatusMessageView.setText(R.string.login_progress_signing_in);
        showProgress(true);
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
    }
}

/**
 * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginStatusView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                .alpha(show ? 1 : 0)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator      animation) {
                        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE
                                : View.GONE);
                    }
                });

        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                .alpha(show ? 0 : 1)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE
                                : View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

/**
 * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
 * the user.
 */
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        try {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }

        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            finish();
        } else {
            mPasswordView
                    .setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

The simplest thing you can do is to save the login state in a [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) file. This is a working example from one of my apps. I use a `CheckBox` to let the user decide if the app should store the login state. You can modify that part to save it automatically after the user authenticates.

```
/***** SHAREDPREFERENCES INSTANCES AND STRING FOR THE PATH *****/
SharedPreferences prefsNagSetting;
private static final String NAG_PREFS = "socially_you_nag_prefs";

/* THE EDITOR */
Editor editor;
```

In the `onCreate()`, instantiate the `SharedPreference`:

```
prefsNagSetting = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(NAG_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// GET THE NAG SETTING
boolean blNagSetting = prefsNagSetting.getBoolean(NAG_SETTING, false);

if (blNagSetting == true)   {
    /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
    Intent startMainPage = new Intent(SignIn.this, SplashScreen.class);
    startMainPage.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    startActivity(startMainPage);
    finish();

} else { // NO NEED FOR THE else BLOCK. JUST AN ILLUSTRATION

    // SHOW THE LOGIN SCREEN

}
```

In my app, I have a CheckBox that is used to check if the user wants the app to remember the login. Modify this logical for your own.

```
/* TOGGLE THE CHECKBOX FOR THE NAG SETTING */
chkbxNagSetting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // EDITOR INSTANCE TO SAVE THE NAG SETTING
        editor = prefsNagSetting.edit();

        // GET THE NAG SETTING CHECKBOX
        if (chkbxNagSetting.isChecked())    {

            editor.putBoolean(NAG_SETTING, true);
        } else {
            editor.putBoolean(NAG_SETTING, false);
        }

        editor.commit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to keep the state of user in a boolean variable in [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Then you check the value each time user opens the app and accordingly show either the login activity or the next activity that you want to show after user login. You might want to check the following thread and blog before proceeding:

[Android User Session Management using Shared Preferences](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)

[Android check user logged in before, else start login activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718514/android-check-user-logged-in-before-else-start-login-activity)

[Check login on every activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246952/check-login-on-every-activity)

Hope this helps.