# How do I press HomeButton and app closes, then I want to logout client so if he presses the App Icon again

Tags: java, android

**Like the question been struggling with this for a day now**
I tried out `onPause`, `onStart` etc but they all seem to fire regularly.

My setup is this I discovered a bug in my App.
If I start App gets directed to login screen Activity!
I have all the login possible, but if I press the Home button on my Android phone.
The Middle one. App closes down... I then go back to the icon and press it.
The app opens and automatically passed login activity.

So I tried multiple ways with the different events firing to redirect back to the login screen but nothing is working correctly.

For example, if I trigger a start activity call in the restart event.
but then login activity is overriding everything even starts again after pushing loginbutton.

I hope this explains a bit but I am open to trying anything at this point.!

Comment: Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246952/check-login-on-every-activity

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. It got solved in ten minutes. how to make an answer?